# query using two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table: users
===============
id   | name    |
===============
 1   | steve   |
 2   | peter   |
================

Table: relation_favorites
=======================
| idFavorite | idUser |
=======================
|     1      |   1    |
|     2      |   1    |
|     4      |   1    |
|     5      |   1    |
|     1      |   2    |
|     3      |   2    |
|     4      |   2    |
|     5      |   2    |
=======================
```

i want to select all the users with the favorite 1 AND 4 AND 5.
i think that i need to use a LEFT JOIN but i cant see it how to do it.

it doesnt work:

```
$query = "SELECT rf.id, u.id idUser
          FROM  users u, relation_favorites rf
          WHERE rf.idUser = u.id
          AND rf.idFavorite = 1
          AND rf.idFavorite = 4
          AND rf.idFavorite = 5";
```

it works but this isnt what i want:

```
$query = "SELECT rf.id, u.id idUser
          FROM  users u, relation_favorites rf
          WHERE rf.idUser = u.id
          AND rf.idFavorite = 1";
```

Comment: Never use implicit (comma-) join syntax. Always use explicit JOIN syntax. (But actually, this isn't about INNER vs OUTER JOINs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a JOIN and COUNT:-

```
SELECT u.id AS idUser, COUNT(rf.idFavorite) AS favourite_count
FROM  users u
INNER JOIN relation_favorites rf
ON rf.idUser = u.id
WHERE rf.idFavorite IN (1, 4, 5)
GROUP BY idUser
HAVING favourite_count = 3
```

You could also use multiple joins:-

```
SELECT u.id AS idUser
FROM  users u
INNER JOIN relation_favorites rf1
ON rf1.idUser = u.id AND rf1.idFavorite = 1
INNER JOIN relation_favorites rf2
ON rf2.idUser = u.id AND rf2.idFavorite = 4
INNER JOIN relation_favorites rf3
ON rf3.idUser = u.id AND rf3.idFavorite = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select name from user 
where id in
(Select distinct idUser from relation_favorites wher  idFavorite in(1,4,5))
```

Try this subquery may be it work for you.

or

you may be try this both query output same

```
Select distinct name from user x
join relation_favorites y
on x.Id=y.IdUser
where y.idFavorite in(1,4,5)
```

EDIT : Try this Query

```
Select x.Name from Users x
join relation_favorites y
on x.Id=y.IdUser
where y.idFavorite in (1,3,4)
Group By x.Name
Having Count(y.IdUser)=3
```

Comment: it doesnt work.
if i do Select name from users where id in (Select distinct idUser from relation_favorites where idFavorite in(1,3,4))
i only should see peter but i see peter and steve

Answer (score -1):

Try this query .

```
select u.id,u.name,rf.idFavorite,rf.idUser from users u,relation_favorites rf where rf.idFavorite = u.id and rf.idFavorite IN (1,4,5);
```

hope it works